# Angular 2: can't get dynamic FormGroup working

Tags: javascript, forms, typescript, angular

I'm playing with Angular 2 (rc4) but I'm experiencing a little issue.

I have a  form built with `FormBuilder` which works well.

Since Plunker seems to use angular RC0, you can get an example of what's wrong [here](https://github.com/mildful/stackoverflow-dynamic-form-builder). It's based on angular quick start so simply do:

```
npm i
npm start
```

`FormComponent` takes an input `Person` which is the person to edit. This input is dynamically provided by the parent of `FormComponent`. When I click on a person, the `FormComponent` sets up a new form via `ngOnChanges()`. Why `OnChanges` ? Because the `FormComponent` is updated, not re-rendered.

### So what's the issue?

The changes done in my `FormComponent` are not tracked by the angular's form if I switch to another person.

#### How to reproduce

Expected behavior:

- edit the name without switching to another person
- submit the form
- `myForm.value` contains the new name - as expected.

Issue :

- select another person via `App`, `FormComponent` is correctly updated
- edit the name
- submit
- `myForm.value` contains the old name. I can't update it.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I've just tried a workaround by using `removeControl` and `addControl` but it results in the same behavior (loop on the `myForm.controls` on changes and use those two functions to update `myForm` instead of instance it again).

Comment: If you use the `New >` button in Plunker you get a template for the most recent Angular2 version. You can also use https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html as a starting point.